# NSE within plotly color factors

Tags: r, dplyr, plotly, nse

I am trying to design a function where there are multiple inputs on what factors can control how a chart is colored. I am trying to use a character string to desegnate the column of the data.frame to use, but it is not working within the `color =` paramater of the plotly statement. Many Thanks

> Error in !as.name(desired_factor) : invalid argument type

```
require(dplyr)
require(plotly)


set.seed(42)


df <- data.frame(x = rep(LETTERS[1:5], 3), 
                 y = rexp(15, rate = 0.5),
                 z = c(rep("Adam", 5), rep("Arthur", 5), rep("Ford", 5)))
df <- arrange(df, desc(z))


df$z2 <- c(rep("a", 5), rep("b", 5), rep("c", 5))

desired_factor <- "z2"


plot_ly(df, 
        x = ~x, 
        y = ~y, 
        color = ~factor(!!as.name(desired_factor)), 
        colors = "Blues", 
        type = "bar") %>% 
  layout(barmode = "stack")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plotly doesn't support [quasiquotation](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/quasiquotation.html). Instead, it uses formulas to specify column names. You have a couple of options:

**Option 1: Dynamically construct the formula**

```
fm <- as.formula( paste0("~factor(", desired_factor ,")") )

plot_ly(df, 
        x = ~x, 
        y = ~y, 
        color = fm,             # <-- NOTE: no ~
        colors = "Blues", 
        type = "bar") %>% 
  layout(barmode = "stack")
```

**Option 2: Construct and evaluate the plotly expression in its entirety**

```
ee <- rlang::expr(
  plot_ly(df, 
          x = ~x, 
          y = ~y, 
          color = ~factor(!!as.name(desired_factor)), 
          colors = "Blues", 
          type = "bar") %>% 
    layout(barmode = "stack"))

eval(ee)
```

Comment: This is great stuff. Thank you for being kind enough to show two examples on how to generate a solution.